# How to get output from a jupyter notebook cell in which no variable name is specified?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I forgot to specify a variable name to  the output, and the return value of the code was shown below the cell. The problem is, I need to get the result
but I have no variable name to use. Do I need to specify a name and re-run the cell? Is there a time saving way to get the “anonymous” variable?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pur9g.png)

Comment: You can use underscore (_) to get the output of last expression in interpreter.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using 'Out[43]' as a variable.

[image: Check this example]